# NetSuite SuiteScript 2.0 - How to use context.newRecord in dynamic mode

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am trying to figure out how you can specify that context.newRecord be in dynamic mode. I have a beforeSubmit UE script and I need the record to be in dynamic mode.

In 1.0, I can just do nlapiGetNewRecord({recordmode: 'dynamic'}); but if I tried context.newRecord({isDynamic: true}), I get an error.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you appear to have taken advantage of *an undocumented feature* within SS1.0:

[image]

SS2.0 shows the *type* as *DeferredDynamicRecord* (the same as `record.load({...isDynamic:false})`) vs. *DynamicRecord* as you get when using `record.load({...isDynamic: true})`

Even worse, the `context` object appears to contain a copy of the `newRecord` object, and is not (at least at the time it's available to us) actually executing an api call to *retrieve* it.

All signs point to you **can't** edit the `newRecord` object in dynamic mode in either of the *Submit methods.